# How to lockdown grails spring security / cas application?

Tags: security, spring, grails, cas

I've tried the standard Config setting

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
```

but this results in a redirect loop.

I've also tried

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
        '**':    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```

but they simply have no effect. Out of what I've tried so far, only controller annotations are working but I'd really prefer a whitelist approach.

Answer (score 3):

The way it worked for me was:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/js/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/css/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/images/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/login/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/logout/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use

```
 '/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
```

and make sure it is the last entry in your url map.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the job but thanks for pointing out the typo. I had actually tried it with a slash there already, but I didn't know it should be the last. When I add this rule, even completely by itself then it has no effect and everything is still open!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I was missing:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
```

which tells grails to use the InterceptUrlMap